# How do i count how many times a component has been called Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

i would like to know if there's a way to count the times a component has been called but from inside the component, not from the father.

In this case i need to know exactly how many times the same component to do some stuffs later, is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to know how many times a component has been instantiated by angular, or how many times a specific method has been called?

If the former, you could use a static property:

```
static callCounter: number = 0

constructor() {
  NameOfThisClass.callCounter++;
}
```

Otherwise if you just want to track a specific method in the same instance of a component:

```
callCounter: number = 0;

myMethod() {
  this.callCounter++;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I was trying to count how many times the component was instantiated. Thanks a lot.